# Why is my conditional formatting not working? Highlight date if within next 7 days

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUBrm.png)

So almost all of my rules are working fine, apart from the top one. I want this rule to colour text in column K red if it is a date within the next 7 days. Can't work out what I'm doing wrong, any suggestions? Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzJ4Q.png)

Added pic of the formula that isn't working - trying to make any dates in column K turn red if they are within the next 7 days

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "=" sign and you're starting from K2 instead of K1. Try:

```
=K1<(Today()-7)
```